# FCM notification badge number on app icon

Tags: android

how can we show a badge count on app icon when the app is closed / at background? As far as I know, I can use the third party lib (like ShortcutBadger)to set the count on the app icon but the problem is when android app is at background, notification is handled at the system tray, and my code will not be processed (please notice me if I am wrong). 
how can I set the count number on app icon??

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setContentTitle("New Messages")
    .setContentText("You've received 3 new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
    .setNumber(messageCount)
    .build();
```

.setNumber(messageCount) will be added as luncher icon badge in api level 26

Comment: where should I call this piece of code?? in public void onMessageReceived??

Comment: But when the app is at background / closed, will this piece of code be run? Because  it seems FCM notification is handled by the system tray rather than by the code. and also, is messageCount a value that sent from server?